# Get minimum of related model date field (django)

Tags: python, django

I have the two following classes:

```
class Incident(models.Model):
    iid = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    person = models.ForeignKey('Person', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)


class Source(models.Model):

    sid = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    incident = models.ForeignKey('Incident', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    url = models.TextField(validators=[URLValidator()])
    datereported = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
```

I want to create a field within the Incident that will pull the minimum datereported of related sources. Is this best done in the model, or in the template? Unsure what best practice is, or how to execute in this case.

Comment: Do you mean the `datereported` itself, or the corresponding `Source` object?

Comment: the datereported itself! but i am curious about returning the source object too. is it the same process?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is this best done in the model, or in the template?

Well a template should - strictly speaking - **not** contain *business logic*. It should contain *render logic*. It should thus specify *how* something should be visible, not *what* should be visible. So it dos not really belong in the template layer, only in the model layer.

You can obtain the smallest `datereported` with:

```
from django.db.models import Min

class Incident(models.Model):
    iid = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    person = models.ForeignKey('Person', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)

    @property
    def first_reporteddate(self):
        return self.source_set.aggregate(first=Min('datereported'))['first']
```

This will *ignore* `Source`s with `datereported` set to `None` (so if there are multiple sources, it takes the smallest `datereported` that is not `None`). If there are no `Source` with a `datereported` not equal to `None`, or no related `Source`s at all, it will return `None` however, since the minimum of an empty set is considered to be `NULL` (in SQL, or `None` in Python/Django).

You can then use this in the template like:

```
{{ some_incident.first_reporteddate }}
```

In case you want the entire object, you can use `self.source_set.order_by('datereported').first()` which will give you the *earliest* related `Source` instance. But this will have a (quite) small impact on performance (it will take a bit longer). In that case Django will fetch *all* columns into memory first. If you thus only need *one* column, this will result in the fact that you did some *useless* serialization (at the database end) and deserialization (at the Python end).

Answer (score 2):

You can use model's property for this:

```
class Incident(models.Model):
    iid = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    person = models.ForeignKey('Person', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)

    @property
    def first_datereported(self):
        first_source = self.source_set.order_by('datereported').first()
        if first_source:
            return first_source.datereported
```

In template or in any other part of code you can use `first_datereported` as normal model's field:

```
{{ incident_instance.first_datereported }}
```

Comment: i think you need to add the check for `None` in `last_source`

Comment: Won't this return the *first* `datereported`? In that case `first_datereported` probably is a better name (or `earliest_reporteddate`).